# Can I manually trigger signals in Django?

Tags: python, django, signals, django-signals

I've written some signals in my Django app that are supposed to send out an email when a particular model instance is created or modified, but the signal receiver function doesn't seem to be responding; at any rate, I'm not getting any emails through (although I have already checked that I'm able to send emails with my current configuration).

Anyhow; I wondered, is it possible to manually send a post_save signal for debugging purposes, rather than trying to trigger it by creating a new model instance each time? Thanks!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#sending-signals):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

instance = MyModel(field='qwerty')
post_save.send(MyModel, instance=instance, created=True)
```

Comment: Ah! I read the Django docs on signals a few times but somehow I didn't grok that - seems obvious in retrospect. Thanks! :)

Comment: can't i just do instance.save() to trigger it??

Comment: @VaibhavVishal That would result in an unnecessary, slow and expensive DB roundtrip

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.